# Не обновляется значение в div. JS

Tags: javascript, html

Есть EventListener на "click":

```
calcButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    message = convertToArray(document.getElementById("message").value);
    result.innerText = codeMessage(message, binaryNumbers.first, binaryNumbers.second);
});
```

При нажатии на кнопку рассчитать берётся значение из input'а, передаётся в функцию codeMessage и результат должен выводиться в результирующий div. При первом рассчёте всё  выводится, но если менять входящее значение - результат в блоке не меняется, хотя в консоле я вижу, что новое значение рассчитано.
То есть в результате при нажатии на кнопку должно было появиться 00 11 01 00 01 11 00, но значение не поменялось

Функция сodeMessage, если нужна:

```
function codeMessage(message, firstCoderBinaryNumber, secondCoderBinaryNumber) {
    result = "";
    message.unshift(0,0);
    for (let i = 0; i < message.length; i++) { 
        let sequence = [ message[i+2], message[i+1], message[i] ]
        result += String(calcCoder(sequence, firstCoderBinaryNumber)) + String(calcCoder(sequence, secondCoderBinaryNumber)) + " ";
    }

    console.log(result);
    return result;
}

function calcCoder(numbers, coderBinaryNumber) {
    let result = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < coderBinaryNumber.length; i++) {
        if (coderBinaryNumber[i] == 1) {
            if(numbers[i] === undefined) numbers[i] = 0;
            result = result ^ numbers[i];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: мы не знаем. что у вас выводится в консоль и на каком этапе, откуда тут знать почему не меняется?

Comment: Что такое result? Добавьте пример, это же всего пару строк кода

Comment: result = document.getElementById("result");

Это результирующий блок, в который подставляется вычисленное значение
Если нужна сама функция codeMessage, то я добавил в пост

Answer (score 1):

Вы переписываете значения наружных переменных. Не хватает названий?

```
function codeMessage(message, firstCoderBinaryNumber, secondCoderBinaryNumber) {
  let result = "";
  ^^^
  ...

calcButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  let message = convertToArray(document.getElementById("message").value);
  ^^^
  ...
```